# How to formulate an ajax url in an external js file in Django?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

I have a registration form for my student user where I ask him to enter an email address. On keyup, I want to verify whether that user exists in the database. If yes, I will prevent him from submitting the form. How do I achieve this?

Here are my files.
P.S: username=email

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('login/', views.login, name="login"),
    path('signup/', views.signup, name="signup"),
    path('validate_stud_username', views.validate_stud_username, 
    name='validate_stud_username'),
 ]
```

views.py

```
def validate_stud_username(request):
    username = request.GET.get('stud_email', None)
    response = {
        'is taken': 
 User.objects.filter(username__iexact=username).exists()
    }
    return JsonResponse(response)
```

signup.html

```
<form action="{% url 'signup' %}" id="stud_registration_form" 
method="POST" >
{% csrf_token %}

 <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
 <input type="email" id="stud_email" style="color: black;" 
 name="stud_email" value="" placeholder=" Email" 
 autocapitalize="none" required>
 <span style="color: red;" class="error_form" id="stud_email_err"> 
 </span>
 <div class="login_btn_wrapper register_btn_wrapper login_wrapper ">
 <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block login_btn" type="submit" 
 style="padding: 2% 0;"> Sign Up </button>
 </div>
 </form>
```

form_validations.js

```
$("#stud_email").keyup(function () {
$.ajax({
  data: $(this).serialize(),
  url: "/validate_stud_username/",

  success: function (response) {
    if (response.is_taken == true) {
      $("#stud_email").addClass("invalid");
    } else {
      $("#stud_email").addClass("valid");
    }
  },
});
check_stud_email();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the URL to your HTML file and access it in your JS file as follows:

**signup.html**

```html
<form action="{% url 'signup' %}" id="stud_registration_form" method="POST" data-url="{% url 'validate_stud_username' %}">
```

**form_validations.js**

```js
$.ajax({
   data: $(this).serialize(),
   url: $('form#stud_registration_form').data('url'),
   ...
```

OR

You can add the Django URL tag directly in your external JS file:

**form_validations.js**

```js
$.ajax({
   data: $(this).serialize(),
   url: "{% url 'validate_stud_username' %}",
   ...
```

Though the last approach is not best practice.

Comment: why is the last one not regarded as a good approach?

Comment: In my opinion, it is best to keep all Django template tags and filters in the core HTML file. But you're free to do whatever you want. Hope my answer helped you out.